# Why code in Promise executes synchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, long-running-processes

In my project I have a very long running operation, so I decided to put it in a `Promise` because I thought that in this way I could continue to execute the other operations while the code inside the `Promise` was running.

While debugging, I find out that the code outside the `Promise` executed only when the code inside the `Promise` finished executing.

Here is an example of what I'm doing in my project (it simulates a long operation, so it takes a while):

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 1000000000) {
    i++
  }
  console.log("Executing inside Promise");
});

console.log("Executing outside Promise");
```

I am not really sure why this is happening and that's why I asked it. But I think that it is somehow related to the fact that the code inside the `Promise` is synchronous.
Indeed when it is async (i.e. the `setTimeout()` method) it runs after the outside code finishes executing.

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 1000000000) {
      i++
    }
    console.log("Executing inside Promise");
  }, 3000)
});

console.log("Executing outside Promise");
```

But I still can't figure out why the code inside the `Promise` is executing synchronously?
Shouldn't it execute asynchronously?

Comment: Promises don't make synchronous code asynchronous. You typically to use something like `setTimeout()` that is already async inside the promise and the promise just makes it convenient to know when it's done.

Comment: As @MarkMeyer said, promises don't make something that's synchronous asynchronous, they just provide a standard way of observing the result of an operation (usually an asynchronous one). But `setTimeout` won't help with that loop, it'll just make it hog the main UI thread at a different time. You'll need a web worker.

Comment: all js code runs sync, it's single-threaded after all. the host must schedule tasks, but code still runs top-down until those escape hatches are reached.

Comment: How could the documents (MDN) be any clearer? "The executor function is executed **immediately**"

Answer (score 3):

The code inside the Promise constructor is meant to run synchronously. A reason for this is that it allows you to do:

```
var resolve, reject
var p = new Promise(function (res, rej) { resolve = res; reject = rej })
// you can return this `p` from a function or use it with p.then()
// then later
resolve(value)
```

Note that long running code like your `for` loop is *always* blocking, even if you run it inside a `setTimeout`. If you run it in a timeout it will just block everything else at a different time. The asynchronous part of Promises is useful for I/O things like network request, which require waiting for a result. That `for` loop doesn't require waiting, in fact it's very very hard at work :). If you need to run expensive code in parallel, you have to use something like [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) in the browser or the new [worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html) API in Node.js.

Comment: Thank you for answering @goto-bus-stop Can I use the technology used for networking (along with WebWorkers and worker_threads) to run long operations? What is it?