# Calling Match Template in Promise.All No Performace Improvement?

Tags: node.js, opencv, async-await, promise, template-matching

I am using OpenCV4NodeJS-prebuilt for my project to use match template.

I Created Two Files one being Index.js and other named matchTemlate.js

In Index.js i call match template:

```
const { matchTemplate } = require("./matchTemplate");
...

let a = async function () {

  let tm = performance.now();
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      matchTemplate(baseImage, templateR),
      matchTemplate(baseImage, templateL)
    ]).then(result => {
      const c = result.map((ob) => (ob.C)) // confidence
      top = c[0] > c[1] ? result[0].Y + 8 : result[1].Y + 11
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  tm = performance.now() - tm;

  console.log(tm)
}
```

and this is matchTemplate.js

```
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs-prebuilt')

exports.matchTemplate = async function (inputFile, templateImage) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
    const matS = await cv.imdecodeAsync(templateImage)

    console.time('templateMatching')
    const matched = inputFile.matchTemplate(matS, 3)
    console.timeEnd('templateMatching')

    const minMax = matched.minMaxLoc()
    return ({ Y: minMax.maxLoc.y, C: minMax.maxVal })
}
```

The log output of matchTemplate is:
`templateMatching: 892.648ms templateMatching: 890.387ms`

and The Log output of index.js is:
`TemplateMatching: 1824.8019220000133`

Why there is no improvement is speed ?
while the execution is done in parallel why it's still taking time equal to time taken by both ?

I tried `Promise.all` method to call ghostscript via gs4fb npm package and convert PDF to Image and the time improvement was there.

By time improvement i mean the difference of total time taken by `Promise.all` method and calling the functions one by one.

Comment: "*while the execution is done in parallel*" it isn't done in parallel. Async doesn't mean there is multithreading - the code is still executed on the same thread.

Comment: (Not directly related to the question) Shouldn't we have some sort of canonical about async != parallel? It shows up a lot and I know I've seen it explained over and over. But is there a good canonical to just link to?

Comment: @VLAZ https://stackoverflow.com/q/50278356/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386537/why-code-in-promise-executes-synchronously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876344/correct-way-to-write-a-non-blocking-function-in-node-js

Comment: `inputFile.matchTemplate` does not appear to be asynchronous, as you do not `await` it.